# How to send notifications on Facebook when User is offline?

Tags: facebook, notifications, access-token

I'm making an app that will integrate with the system I've got.
The idea is that in some events that occur within my system, the app can send notifications to users via Facebook.
That is, my app does not necessarily have to have something inside Facebook, the initial idea was only notify the user by Facebook about some event in my system, and when the user clicks on the notification, it would be redirected to my system.

Is this possible? Cause I'm having trouble keeping the Access Token, because those events will occur mostly when the user is offline, and if Access Token I have are invalid for any reason, I will have to get a new one because there is no as the user "re-authorize" my app because it would not be online at the time of the event.

Comment: Creating a notification only requires the _app_ access token. But notifications are only available for canvas apps as of now, not for external websites.

Comment: As CBroe said, the notification are only available for canvas applications and require the user already authorized that application. If you create a canvas application, after user authenticated you could  the application access_token to send notification whenever you want. And you notifications will automatically redirect to your canvas application.

Comment: This part of needing canvas app I get it, but my question is if there is any method to send the notification for my application, if the access token is not valid and the user is offline.